# Loading a Rdata file inside a function

Tags: r

I have a function to which I have to pass the dataset.

```
loading <- function(dataset){
merchants <- load(dataset)
return(merchants)
}
```

But when I use the loading function it returns a character vector

```
loading("capital.Rdata")
"capital"
```

How do I load the data inside the function?

Comment: Maybe also provide or return your environment...

Answer (score 5):

The `load()` command doesn't return the object stored in the RData file. Instead, it returns a character vector that lists the names of all the objects that were loaded from the Rdata file. Your object is apparently called `capital`, so you could perhaps do something like this:

```
loading <- function(dataset){
   merchants <- load(dataset)
   return(get(merchants))
}
```

You pass the `get()` function a string and it returns the object of that name.

Note that this won't work if there is more than one object saved in the RData file. Checking for the presence of more than one object, and potentially returning all objects, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `get` only retrieves 1 object at a time.  Use `mget` for multiple objects.

Comment: No worries. You should accept whichever answer you used to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `envir` argument of `load` to control the place where the loaded variables are stored.

Save some variables (to make this reproducible):

```
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10)
z <- letters
save(x, y, z, file = "test.RData")
```

Define your loading function.  This will return an environment containing `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```
loading <- function(rdata_file)
{
  e <- new.env()
  load(rdata_file, envir = e)
  e
}
```

Usage is as:

```
data_env <- loading("test.RData")
ls.str(data_env)
## x :  int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
## y :  num [1:10] 0.6843 0.6922 0.3194 0.0588 0.0146 ...
## z :  chr [1:26] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `ls()`. You should have variables you saved in `"capital.Rdata"` loaded. Your function returns the variable name you saved, which in this case should be `capital`.